# Take too long time to connect to server through ssh if IP not specified in /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, dns, hosts

My Ubuntu 10.10 computer is in an intranet. If I don't specify server's IP in `/etc/hosts`, it takes a long time to connect and sometimes fails.

Do you know why?

Comment: I'd say: check your DNS availability

Comment: I have set up the DNS, and the DNS is ok

Comment: Try `ssh -v`; it should explain what is happening.

Comment: when I type `ssh -v`, I see that the ssh client program pauses a few seconds  around `Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As root edit “/etc/ssh/sshd_config” and add the line “UseDNS no“.

executing the command

```
sudo echo "UseDNS no" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

This might help you if this is the reason for your slow connection issue.